# Access: Inner join query not producing results

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010, inner-join

I'm trying to perform a query (using Access 2010) on the following tables:

```
Contact   |   Facility_Contact   |   Facility   |   Bank
          |                      |              |     
ID        |   (fk) Contact_ID    |      ID      |   ID
CName     |   (fk) Facility_ID   |    FName     |   BName
          |                      |    BNumber   |   BNumber
```

I would like the final result to display:

```
CName | FName | BName
```

Here is the query:

```
SELECT 
  HUD.[HOLDER NAME], Facility.PROVNAME, Contact.LAST_NAME

FROM 
  Facility INNER JOIN Bank ON Facility.[BNumber] = Bank.[BNumber]) INNER JOIN
  (Contact INNER JOIN Facility_Contact ON Contact.[ID] = Facility_Contact.[Contact_ID]) ON Facility.[ID] = Facility_Contact.[Facility_ID];
```

This doesn't produce any results.

The problem comes up when I add the "Bank" table. Queries from Contact to Facility work, as do queries from Facility to Bank. However I'm having difficulty producing results when trying to link from Contact to Bank.

Maybe a Where-like clause somewhere? But now I'm speaking of things that I'm not too familiar with ;)

Thank you all!

Comment: what is HUD in your join criteria on bank? it seems to be referenced out of nowhere

Comment: Good catch, should be changed to bank. But that's just writing into SO. will edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FROM 
  Facility INNER JOIN Bank ON Facility.[BNumber] = HUD.[BNumber])`

You close a paranthetical but never open it. Although that would result in an error, so I assume that is a typo.

---

`Facility INNER JOIN Bank ON Facility.[BNumber] = HUD.[BNumber]`

You are joining `Facility` with `Bank` but then in your ON clause you state that `Facility.[BNumber] = HUD.[BNumber]` Where did HUD come from? This is not good.

---

`Facility INNER JOIN Bank ON Facility.[BNumber] = HUD.[BNumber]) INNER JOIN (Contact INNER JOIN Facility_Contact ON Contact.[ID] = Facility_Contact.[Contact_ID]) ON Facility.[ID] = Facility_Contact.[Facility_ID];`

Your schema appears to be Facility->Bank; Facility->Facility_contact->Contact. Consider rewriting to reflect this (This is just for readability):

```
FROM 
    Facility 
    INNER JOIN Bank ON Facility.[BNumber] = Bank.[BNumber]
    INNER JOIN Facility_Contact ON Facility.[ID] = Facility_Contact.[Facility_ID]
    INNER JOIN Contact ON Facility_Contact.[Contact_ID] = Contact.[ID]
```

Now to get records returned all of those joins need contain data. There needs to be a matching `BNUMBER` in your `Bank` table for each `BNumber` in `Facility` table. There needs to be a matching `facility_id` in your `Facility_Contact` table for each `ID` in your `Facility`. There needs to be a matching `ID` in your `Contact` table for each `Contact_ID` in your `Facility_Contact` table. If any of these links are missing you will get 0 records. If you want to show Facilties and Bank Names regardless if they have a Facility Contact then consider using a LEFT JOIN instead:

```
FROM 
    Facility 
    INNER JOIN Bank ON Facility.[BNumber] = Bank.[BNumber]
    LEFT JOIN Facility_Contact ON Facility.[ID] = Facility_Contact.[Facility_ID]
    LEFT JOIN Contact ON Contact.[ID] = Facility_Contact.[Contact_ID]
```

This won't drop results just because you don't have a contact at the facility yet. Or that contact hasn't been set up in the Contact table.